# Perl Mechanize Firefox onchange event or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl

I've been struggling with this for hours.  I'm trying to perform a click inside a selection list and there appears to be an onchange event involved.  I don't know Javascript at all.

Basically, I'm logging into the following website: www.guidestar.org

To use the Advanced Search, you need to register.  So I did that with a throw away email account/password.  I automated the login so far, and then go to the Adv Search page and select my values and get to the results of my search.

It's at this results page where I'm having issues clicking on one of the "Refine By Category", "By income" selection options.  I can mechanize and get the first value selected, for example: $100k - $500k (2), but selecting is probably not what I want, I need to somehow click the value.  If I manually (without the script) click on the value, it advances the page properly.

Here's the code I have so far and commented out various attempts.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
 use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak; # Ensure weak references in use

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $log         = 'c:\perl_script_logs\script_log';
my $log_errors  = 'c:\perl_script_logs\script_errors_log';

open STDOUT, '>', $log or die "Can't write to $!";
open STDERR, '>', $log_errors or die "Can't write to $!";

# login
my $login_page  = 'https://www.guidestar.org/Login.aspx';
my $user        = 'email@somewhere.com';
my $pw          = '********';


my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->allow( javascript => 1 );
$mech->get($login_page); 
$mech->field('ctl00$phMainBody$LoginMainsite$UserName', $user);
$mech->field('ctl00$phMainBody$LoginMainsite$Password', $pw);
$mech->click_button( value => 'Sign In', );

if ( $mech->success() ) {
    print "Successful login\n";
} else {
    print "Not a successful login\n";
}

# go to adv search page
my $adv_search = 'http://www.guidestar.org/AdvancedSearch.aspx';

$mech->get($adv_search);

$mech->select('ctl00$phMainBody$orgSearchConfiguration_state$gslbList', 'CA' );
$mech->select('ctl00$phMainBody$orgSearchConfiguration_categorydesc$gslbList', ['3', '4x19', '5', '6', '8x44']);
$mech->field('ctl00$phMainBody$orgSearchConfiguration_incometotal$tbMin', '500k');
$mech->click({ xpath => '//*[@id="ctl00_phMainBody_ctl08"]' });

# selecting fine, but need to click it somehow or click after select, or execute some JS here... or something.
#$mech->select('ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$listNavValues', '[100001;500001>' );

# tried:
#$mech->click({ xpath => '//*[@id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues"]' });
#$mech->click({ xpath => '//*[@id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues"]/option[1]' });
#$mech->click({ xpath => '//*[@id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues"]/option[1]', synchonize => 0});

#my $click_here = $mech->xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues"]/option[1]', single => 1);
#$mech->click($click_here);

# maybe selector?
#my $select = $mech->selector('#ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues', single => 1);
#$select->__click();
```

Here's the HTML that may be of some assistance:

```
</p><p id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_divNavigator">
  <label>
    By
    Income
  </label>
  <br />
  <select size="6" name="ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$listNavValues" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$listNavValues\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_listNavValues" OnClick="MPNav(this)">
    <option value="[100001;500001>" nameonly="$100K - $500K">$100K - $500K  (2)</option>
    <option value="[500001;1e+006>" nameonly="$500K - $1M">$500K - $1M  (2140)</option>
    <option value="[1e+006;2.5e+006>" nameonly="$1M - $2.5M">$1M - $2.5M  (1946)</option>
    <option value="[2.5e+006;5e+006>" nameonly="$2.5M - $5M">$2.5M - $5M  (908)</option>
    <option value="[5e+006;1e+007>" nameonly="$5M - $10M">$5M - $10M  (591)</option>
    <option value="[1e+007;>" nameonly="Greater than $10M">Greater than $10M  (623)</option>

</select>
  <input name="ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$txtNavName" type="hidden" id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_txtNavName" value="incomenavigator" />
  <input name="ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$txtNavModifier" type="hidden" id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_txtNavModifier" value="incometotal" />
  <input name="ctl00$phMainBody$incomenavigator$txtFieldName" type="hidden" id="ctl00_phMainBody_incomenavigator_txtFieldName" value="Income" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function MPNav(listbox) {
      var navName = listbox.name;
      var nameSplit = navName.split('$');
      if (nameSplit.length >= 2) {
        navName = nameSplit[nameSplit.length - 2];
      }
      var navSelection = listbox.options[listbox.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      var selSplit = navSelection.split(' (');
      if (selSplit.length >= 1) {
        navSelection = selSplit[0];
      }
      switch(navName)
      {
        case 'statenavigator':
          mixpanel.track('Navigator', { 'State' : navSelection });
          break;
        case 'citynavigator':
          mixpanel.track('Navigator', { 'CitySearched': navSelection });
          break;
        case 'incomenavigator':
          mixpanel.track('Navigator', { 'Income': navSelection });
          break;
        case 'assetsnavigator':
          mixpanel.track('Navigator', { 'Assets': navSelection });
          break;
      }
    }
</script>
</p></fieldset>
```